# getting mlflow exception in azure ml compute cluster if I am trying to get the latest version from production

Tags: azureml-python-sdk

I was trying to get a latest model from production using mlflow command,

```
version = client.get_latest_versions(model_name, stages=["Production"])[0].version
```

However this is working fine in local where as if I submit this in Azure compute cluster it is failing with below code.

> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/model-versions/search failed with error code 403 != 200. Response body: ''

I have tried with DefaultAzureCredential and clientsecretcredential as well. Am I missing something here. Do I need to give any extra access?

Comment: can you please share the full code that can help us to figure-out easily.